# Alternate line before shooting down the bug's hijacked ship?

Tags: dialogue, trailers, men-in-black

As a fan of the MIB movies, especially the first, I have this faint memory of seeing an alternate "punchline" or "gag line" between agents J & K before they shoot their big guns at the hijacked Worlds Fair saucer that the Bug has hijacked to escape.  The theatrical version goes like this:

> K: Roaches check in.  [cocks his gun]
>
> J: They don't check out.  [cocks his gun]
>
> [both fire up at the ship]

The alternate I remember, which IMHO was way more fun and cool, went something like this:

> J: You know how to use these things?
>
> [beat]
>
> K: No idea whatsoever.
>
> [both cock their guns and fire up at the ship]

Am I just plain cuckoo, or does anybody remember this from say a trailer or an alternate scene or something?

Comment: I remember a trailer for "Major League" where there was a joke: "That ball wouldn't have left every park."  "Name one."  "Yellowstone."  That scene is not in the movie either.

Comment: @LarsTech Which is a shame. That's a such a great line.

Answer (score 40):

Yes, the end of the first trailer uses this line:

However, only K cocks the gun, before it is spoken.